# Key type for Factory implementation in Golang

Tags: go, design-patterns

This is my first question on StackOverflow. Please be kind. :)

I have a bunch of modules, each of which has a few getter functions. I am planning to unify the access of these getters by use of a factory.

```
type CommonGetterModule struct {
  cf *ContextFactory
}

func (cm *CommonGetterModule) get(key KEYTYPE, context string) interface{} {
  ctx := cm.cf.get(context)
  return ctx.get(key)
}
```

The issue here is that the get calls implemented by each module differs by number of query parameters that together constitute the key. This would be solved best by use of named variables, but those are mysteriously absent from golang.

```
type Module1 struct {
}

func (c *Module1) get(key KEYTYPE) interface{} {
  // interpret the type of key
  keyType := determineKeyType(key)
  switch keyType {
  case keyType1: getForKeyType1(key[0], key[1])
  case keyType2: getForKeyType2(key[1])
  case keyType1: getForKeyType3(key[0], key[2])
  }
```

KEYTYPE can be some number of strings that can be interpreted by individual modules as part of their get methods. The expected calls can be as follows:

```
var cm CommonGetterModule
// key1 := {userid: "A10", productid: 200}
cm.get(key1, USER_CONTEXT)
// key2 := {userid: "A10", productid: 200, expiry:"2022JAN"}
cm.get(key2, USER_CONTEXT)
// key3 := {productsymbol:"ABCD"}
cm.get(key3, PRODUCT_CONTEXT)
```

I have narrowed down my choices of KEYTYPE implementation to these:

- map[ParameterType]ParameterValue
- a struct with all possible values across modules

```
type AllKeyTypes struct {
  userid string
  expiry string
  productid int
  productsymbol string
}
```

- some form of variadic function

a. Which will be my best option?

b. Is it even worth doing?

Comment: What is the point of doing something like this? Are you trying to make it run faster, or shorten the code, or do something else?

Comment: @BurakSerdar performance is not the concern. There is a common behaviour that I wish to implement in each of the modules exposing getter functions. I assumed the best way to do that is by routing all my gets through a common getter, which can take care of the special behaviour.

Comment: Based on your description, all those getters have different signatures and different semantics. There is nothing to be gained from combining such functionality. You'll end up writing more code and it will be difficult to maintain because it'll introduce unnecessary artificial coupling between unrelated pieces.

Comment: @BurakSerdar That makes sense. However I still need to ensure that common behaviour is addressed. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea behind Go language is simplicity, not going java-abstraction way of things. So having factories with abstract modules should be justified & **probably** not worth having that

Main concern re your approach is a complex key type.
It's unclear what kind of combinations are supported, so you probably have to go into source code to understand before calling a method OR have a rich documentation on use-cases, which is not good
Instead of having a single method `Get(key KEYTYPE)` try to have multiple methods with each own signature, like

```
GetByID(id string)
GetByUserIDProductID(userID, productID string)
GetByProductSymbol(symbol string)
```

It's simpler & more straightforward.

Also, method parameters can be optional, so you can support multiple cases in a single method if needed. It will be still more readable, like

```golang
// GetProduct returns a product by it's ID, with optional 'symbol' filter value match
GetProduct(id, symbol string)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I see your point about bringing Java abstractions. The community seems to concur with that.
The issue with multiple Get methods at the CommonModule level is that each module has its own set of getters with different params. e.g. GetById might be implemented by module1 but not module2. So having each module implement them seems counterproductive.

Comment: @harrissravan in such scenario ModuleAdapter implementation seems reasonable.: 1 super-module class with multiple generalized methods can be a trade-off.

So you can have 1 entry point module to the logic, but various implementations hidden.